# Is there a "local timezone" suffix?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, timezone

Is there any convention to add in a local timezone (whatever the user has set it as) in a database?

For example, like I can do the following for UTC time:

- `2014-01-01 01:02:03Z`

Is there something like the following to mean local time?

- `2014-01-01 01:02:03L`

Or some other suffix where it can either pick up the user's system time or take it from a variable that can be set? For example, something like (for Postgres):

```
ALTER DATABASE postgres SET timezone TO 'Europe/Berlin';
```

Comment: As a pedantic note, `Z` is not a time zone, but a clock. It's equivalent to Universal Time Clock. Time zones can be measured in square miles, while clocks are just clocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Postgres.

The format you're asking about is ISO 8601.  Specifically in that format, the absence of a `Z` or an offset such as `-07:00` or `+05:30` is defined as "local time".

So what you are looking for is a string without an offset, such as `2014-01-01T01:02:03`.

Comment: ok, but then in that case how would you know **IF** there is a timezone or not? For example, from the string you've supplied it can be either a datetime or a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

postgres would use the system timezone, or what you called local, if no timezone is specified. see [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

> If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.

> ...

> Conversions between timestamp without time zone and timestamp with time zone normally assume that the timestamp without time zone value should be taken or given as timezone local time.

Comment: got it, so there's no notation that's used (even outside of Postgres) to indicate -- in the string itself -- that the user 'means' local time?

Comment: system means the server system of course and taht would be used, if the user wans another time zone you need to add it inb the string you send to the server

Comment: No Postgres does not have to use the timezone of the system it is running on. The Postgres setting `TimeZone`  determines what timezone Postgres will use by default. Now `initdb` will generally set `TimeZone` to the system's timezone, but you can change  that in `postgresql.conf` or on the fly to have Postgres use a different timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Your concept is flawed for a couple of reasons:

1. A user in Germany connects to a Web server in England that connects to a database server is America. What constitutes local?
2. More to the point Postgres does not store the time zone in `with time zone` fields. So you will not recover the entered time zone on data retrieval.

If you are dealing with multiple time zones then the field you need to use is `timestamp with time zone`. This will rotate entered timestamp values to UTC for storage. You now have a fixed point in time that you can rotate to whatever 'local' time you want on retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Just treat the undecorated time as a timestamp with time zone:

```
richard=> SET timezone='Europe/London';
SET
richard=> SELECT '2022-08-27 21:42:22.25891'::timestamptz;
         timestamptz          
------------------------------
 2022-08-27 21:42:22.25891+01
(1 row)

richard=> SET timezone='Europe/Paris';
SET
richard=> SELECT '2022-08-27 21:42:22.25891'::timestamptz;
         timestamptz          
------------------------------
 2022-08-27 21:42:22.25891+02
(1 row)
```